# How to get push notification in Top (status bar) in IBM MobileFirst

Tags: javascript, push-notification, ibm-mobilefirst

Everything is working fine in my android app with push notification. but i'm getting notification in alert form. I need notification at the top instead of alert, see image below:

[image]

Comment: Where is your example code? [How to ask a **good** question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

Did you at all look at the code of the sample application that you are running?

1. You get an alert because that is what is specified in the `onNotificationReceived` function
2. Notifications are displayed in the notification area only when the app is in the background for closed. Notifications will not be displayed in the notification area when the application is in the foreground.

Comment: point 2 : that thing I know, but on foreground I want to get notification on top of that application. right now it's came in alert. how to show notification in top of the application.

Comment: Write a cordova plug-in and replace the alerts with plugin invocation. This is a mistake though, you should not put the notification in the notification area when the application is open.